# Webview2 control VUE textarea

Tags: vb.net, vue.js, webview2

How can use the Webview2 to input some value into textarea (VUE) ?

```
document.querySelector("#app > div > main > div > aside > div.container.fluid > div:nth-child(2) > div > form > div > div > div.v-input__slot > div > textarea").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
```

[Original Link](https://g0vhk-io.github.io/HKAddressParser/#/)

Thanks!

I've try to use WebView21.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync is no problem, but when I try to submit the form, the textarea is not have value and checked the website it's VUE, they have some event call oninput like this, so I've change the value it's can't submit, I'am no idea to call VUE function.

Answer (score 0):

use .value instead

```
document.querySelector("#app > ... > textarea").value = "hello world"
```